# Issue getting components to update on state change

Tags: reactjs

When the user presses a button it activates night mode that changes various colors such as the background color. From my understanding when state is changed components that use it should change as well. At the moment I have confirmed the state is changing but the components do not change on screen. Thank you for any assistance.

**States defined here**

```
const[isNightMode, setIsNightMode] = React.useState(false)   //Checks if currently in night mode

  const [nightMode, setNightMode] = React.useState({   //Settings of the actual night mode
    background: "#FFFFFF",
    bannerText: "#000000",
    listText: "#FFFFFF",
    banner: "#48cae4",
  });
```

**Function that triggers state change**

```
function nightmode(){

    if(isNightMode){ 
      setIsNightMode(false);  
    }
    else{
      setIsNightMode(true);
    }

    if(isNightMode){
      setNightMode({background: "#000000"});   //Here the colors are changed 
      setNightMode({bannerText: "#FFFFFF"});   //but the screen does not update
      setNightMode({listText: "#000000"});
      setNightMode({banner: "#48cae4"});
    }
    else{
      setNightMode({background: "#FFFFFF"});
      setNightMode({bannerText: "#000000"});
      setNightMode({listText: "#FFFFFF"});
      setNightMode({banner: "#48cae4"});
    }
  }
```

**Example of component that uses these states that should update**

```
<Card style = {{marginBottom: 25, width: window.innerWidth/4, borderRadius: 30, backgroundColor: nightMode.banner, color: nightmode.bannerText}}>
   <CardContent>
      <div style = {{display: 'flex', fontFamily: 'Work Sans', fontSize: 55}}>
         <text>Tuesday</text>
      </div>
      <text style = {{display: 'flex', fontFamily: 'Work Sans', fontSize: 45}}>11:45</text>
   </CardContent>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setNightMode` should update the object as a whole. not just one property.

```
function nightmode(){

if(isNightMode){ 
  setIsNightMode(false);  
}
else{
  setIsNightMode(true);
}

if(isNightMode){
  setNightMode(
    {
      background: "#000000" , 
      bannerText: "#FFFFFF" ,
      listText: "#000000" , 
      banner: "#48cae4"
    });   
 }
 else{
   setNightMode({
     background: "#FFFFFF" ,
     bannerText: "#000000" ,
     listText: "#FFFFFF",
     banner: "#48cae4"
   });
  
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, out of curiosity why did changing states individually not have the same effect. Shouldn't each color have updated one by one.

Comment: state `nightMode` has the value `{
    background: "#FFFFFF",
    bannerText: "#000000",
    listText: "#FFFFFF",
    banner: "#48cae4",
  }` . `setNightMode()` changes the entire state ,not just part of it. so when you changes the state like `setNightMode({listText: "#000000"})` then the state `nightMode` will be updated to `{listText: "#000000"}` losing other three property. so you have to pas the whole object with the updated property to make your code run just as you expected.